# Can you skin the mapkit on IOS like you can in the Javascript API?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mapkit

I'm writing a custom google-maps based application, and my web version has a nice color scheme to change the look of the google maps overlay. Please tell me you can do the same thing on mapkit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MapKit doesn't give you the same styled map capabilities.